# Accessing only one key in a nested list of dictionaries and plotting it with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a nested list of dictionaries, created like this:

```
N = 30
grid = []
for row in range(N):
   rows = []
   for column in range(N):
      each_cell = {"check": 0, "type": -1}
      rows.append(each_cell)
   grid.append(rows)
```

Type is the one that I want to plot, a value of -1 means nothing in the cell, and 0,1,2,3 are different types (not gradient), which I want to be represented by different colours.

I am putting a random number of types into the grid like this:

```
import numpy.random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range (rnd.randint(0, N*N)):
   x = rnd.randint(0, N)
   y = rnd.randint(0, N)
   grid[x][y]['check'] = 1
   if grid[x][y]['check'] == 1:
      grid[x][y]['type'] = rnd.randint(0,4)
```

I am attempting to plot it using this:

```
plt.imshow(grid['type'], interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = 'gist_ncar_r')
plt.show()
```

But obviously the `grid['type']` isn't picking out only the types like I want it to, anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Is the second code block meant to be run right after the first? I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: To avoid `IndexError: list index out of range`, you should use `rnd.randint(0, N - 1)` when setting `x` and `y`.

Comment: @mfcovington Yes they are, when I run them both together I don't get an error

Comment: What about to rearrange the indices of the multi-array `grid` (so that finally it will become a dict) by writing `grid['check'][x][y]`  and  `grid['type'][x][y]`?

Comment: Actually, you didn't specify that you were using `numpy.random` instead of the built-in `random`. It works as-is with `numpy` version, but not the built-in.

Comment: @Berci I can't get that to change anything, I am always getting     "TypeError: List indices must be integers, not str" It is not grabbing the right things I want from the grid

Comment: Ah ok my bad @mfcovington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `imshow` requires an 'array-like', you can change the structure of your data to make it easier to work with. Instead of using an array of dicts, use a dict of arrays.

```
import numpy.random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 30
grid = {'check': [], 'type': []}

for row in range(N):
    check_rows = []
    type_rows = []
    for column in range(N):
        check_rows.append(0)
        type_rows.append(1)
    grid['check'].append(check_rows)
    grid['type'].append(type_rows)

for i in range (rnd.randint(0, N*N)):
    x = rnd.randint(0, N)
    y = rnd.randint(0, N)
    grid['check'][x][y] = 1
    if grid['check'][x][y] == 1:
        grid['type'][x][y] = rnd.randint(0,4)

plt.imshow(grid['type'], interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = 'gist_ncar_r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This seems to work really well thank you very much! That definitely makes it easier to access specific keys which is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @Berci Haha sorry I didn't quite get what you meant I am pretty new to programming so I apologise for not understanding you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to get the data you want into an array:

```
from numpy import *
...
data = array([[grid[i][j]['type'] for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)])
```

To use `array` you will need to do do the `numpy` import.

Then you can plot it like you're trying to:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(data, interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = 'gist_ncar_r')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, but I am getting `NameError: name 'array' is not defined`